# Sending multiple API calls from react-native

Tags: react-native

In my application, inside the componentDidMount(), I want to dispatch an action, which has 2 API calls. In angular, with observables, we can use forkJoin() to achieve this. In react / react-native, do we have a similar method to forkJoin()? If now, what will be a good practice to call 2 API endpoints?

Comment: Which library are you using to handle your async actions?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for something like in this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866262/several-requests-on-componentdidmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866262/several-requests-on-componentdidmount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also using Promise chaining would be useful.

```
someApiCall().then(function (bun) {
    return addSausage(bun)
}).then(function (bunWithSausage) {
    return addSauce(bunWithSausage)
}).then(function (hotdog) {
    return hotdog
})
```